# A issue occurs in the process of npm install when install the Library of ngx-admin

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm-install, ngx-bootstrap

**Reason**

I try to `npm install` ago when the node.js is 6.11.0,and the npm is 3.3.0,at that time the npm is OK but a issue(Metadata version is mismatch for module ......) occurs later and I type to a code of `npm i npm -g` accroding to (https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/issues/1367) .So the npm's version is 5.6.0 now ,the last issue is resloved at the same time the new issue is occuring.

**Environment**

System:Ubuntu14.04; node.js:6.12.0; npm:5.6.0

**Probloem**

```
kris-allen@krisallen:~/ngx-admin$ npm install
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EINTEGRITY: sha512-WIr7iDkdmdbxu/Gh6eKEZJL6KPE74/5MEsf2whTOFNxbIoIixogroLdKYqB6FDav4Wavh/lZdzzd3b2KxIXC5Q== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-WIr7iDkdmdbxu/Gh6eKEZJL6KPE74/5MEsf2whTOFNxbIoIixogroLdKYqB6FDav4Wavh/lZdzzd3b2KxIXC5Q== but got sha1-EfgjGPX+e7LNIpZaEI6TBiCCFtg=. (1837200 bytes)
npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm WARN tar zlib error: unexpected end of file
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kris-allen/.npm/_logs/2017-11-29T19_48_56_963Z-debug.lo
```

**The picture as fellows:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEGrH.png)

Comment: The problem comes from npm, you should try Yarn, produces lesser errors and quite faster.
you should install yarn https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you can see:

`npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>`

So please report this issue to npm itself with log mentioned above:

`npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kris-allen/.npm/_logs/2017-11-29T19_48_56_963Z-debug.lo`

Comment: But it isn't useful. I try it later.

Comment: Yep, I know. But reading npm log could help, usually it has verbose description of error

Answer (score 1):

I too have encountered this error: do read your own debug log before submitting a ticket. One ticket for a similar issue I saw had a debug log attached clearly showing  the cause to be running out of disk space.

Eventually I found my instance of the problem was caused by stale package-lock.json files causing the integrity checks to fail.  Nothing was wrong with the .tgz files themselves (which makes the error message frustratingly misleading), it was just comparing the integrity check hash with that for the wrong version of the package file archive.  Nothing in the debug log helped much with finding the actual root cause.

I found the following issue (and several dups of it) helpful in figuring this out:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19353

Answer (score 0):

The complex looking problem was solved just with the help of proxy reset.

Run below commands and try.
*npm config rm proxy

npm config rm https-proxy*

If this gives proxy error, try setting the valid proxy and run your commands.
 
*npm config set proxy http://url:port

npm config set https-proxy http://url:port

npm set strict-ssl false* (Optional)

You should be good to go.